# Is there a way to do this?

Tags: headphones

I have a group of 7 people that play RPG games together. The shop they play at gets a bit noisy due to amount of other people playing. Is there something like headsets with mics that we could use so we could just talk to each other without screaming over others.

I was told just headsets with a "jackbox" but I do not know anything about this stuff honestly

Thank you sorry if this isn't a correct place for a question like this